# Teradata convert Integer format '99:99:99.9' to CHAR

Tags: teradata

The data type of the column Extract_Time in the target table is created in the Integer format '99:99:99.9'. The source data is CHAR(7). If the time is 00:55:03 the source data comes like 55037, if it is 18:00:00 the source data comes like 1800000.

The target column data type cannot be changed. I am trying to convert the integer column to char while selecting the data but the output is getting displayed as '***'. Please guide me to convert the Integer format '99:99:99.9' to CHAR when selecting data.

Comment: Can you show your existing CAST?

Comment: What if the time is something like `09:01:01'?  If no element is a fixed size within the string, I think you're going to have a very difficult time.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just tried the below statement and it worked for me. SUBSTR(CAST((Extract_Time (FORMAT '9999999')) AS CHAR(10)) , 1, 6)